# How to send Empty field value as blank (Not Null)

Tags: apex, json, httprequest, http

Apex Code:

```
  List<order_batch__c> bcList = new List<order_batch__c>();
       bcList= [select Or_invoiceadd1__c,Or_invoiceadd2__c,Or_invoiceadd3__c,Or_invoiceadd4__c from order_batch__c  where  Quote_Line_Item__r.Quote1__c= : Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') order by Order_numbering__c]; 
      String JSONString = '';
     for (order_batch__c order : bcList) {
     String orderJSON = '{\n' +
    ' "Or_invoiceadd1__c" :"' + order.Or_invoiceadd1__c + '",\n' +
    '},';
      JSONString +=orderJSON ;
             system.debug( JSONString);
         }
```

> DEBUG :Or_invoiceadd1__c:null

I am sending  json string through http post when the filed data was empty it was returning null i dont want to return it as null .i want to return as blank only .how can i do that one .

Comment: Why don't you just serialize bcList instead of manually building your JSON string? e.g. `json.serializePretty(bcList);`?

Comment: Getting 'null' is the default toString behavoir of objects and fields.  It's good to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue to build a JSON string in the way that you are (rather than using json.serialize) then you'll have to do something like this:

```
' "Or_invoiceadd1__c" :"' + (order.Or_invoiceadd1__c == null ? '' : order.Or_invoiceadd1__c) + '",\n' +
```

Comment: json.serialize i want column in particular order but it is not coming with json.serialize

Comment: Still i am receiving null for the above code

Comment: My bad, wrap it in () as per updated example

Comment: Perfect answer.